# How to change UITextField's text in ViewController when subview UITableView row is selected from a different file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm adding subview (UITableView with delegate from another file (AutocompleteTable.h and .m)) to a ViewController named AddViewController:

```
AddViewController.h
#import "AutocompleteTable.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemName;


AddViewController.m

@interface AddViewController ()
{
    AutocompleteTable *autocompleteDelegate;
}
@end

@implementation AddViewController

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    autocompleteDelegate = [[AutocompleteTable alloc] init];
    ...
    autocompleteTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 320, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    autocompleteTable.delegate = (id)autocompleteDelegate;
    autocompleteTable.dataSource = (id)autocompleteDelegate;
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTable];
}
```

and inside AutocompleteTable.m I'm trying to set AddViewController's itemName.text to selected row's text with didSelectRowAtIndexPath but does not work:

```
AutocompleteTable.h
#import "AddViewController.h"


AutocompleteTable.m

@interface AutocompleteTable()
{
    AddViewController *addController;
}

@end

@implementation AutocompleteTable

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    addController = [[AddViewController alloc] init];
    addController.itemName.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;


    self.hidden = YES;
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
addController = [[AddViewController alloc] init];
```

You're actually creating a new instance of AddViewController every time the cell is selected.  Try getting a reference to the textfield that's actually on the screen and changing that instead.